# How to Access a video gallery with windows phone 8 Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, video, windows-phone-8

I am doing a application for windows phone 8, I would like to upload a video from the video gallery of the smartphone, but apparently a method like "PhotoChooserTask" for the video does not exist.

Does anybody know how to do?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have to upgrade your app to 8.1 version to use this API. Then you can use below method to access video gallery.

```
KnownFolders.VideoLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
```

PS:Do not forget to allow permission for needed capabilities from AppManifest.xml file. You can find more detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639127.aspx).

Comment: it is possible that there is another way with WP 8.0 SDK 8.0? 
Now I've almost finished my project and I would not want to upset everything ... I do not think they have thought about how to implement something so trivial for earlier versions of windows ...

Comment: Unfortunately there is no API to access videos in WP 8.0. Read and write is not available. I think there are security and storage issues about it. Why don't you upgrade 8.1?

Comment: ah ok I get it, I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 can you tell me what are the steps to upgrade the project to windows phone 8.1? 
Thanks!

Comment: If you've installed WP 8.1 SDK, you can right click on your project and choose "Retarget to Windows Phone 8.1" option. That's it. Before doing that I suggest you to backup your project.

Comment: When I go to run the project came to education "KnownFolders.VideoLibrary.GetFilesAsync ();" it gives me the exception "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" even though I unchecked "Removable_Storage" by WMAAppManifest, how is it possible?

Comment: Did you allow Videos Library capability in package.appxmanifest file?

Comment: ok, well does not give me more than the exception. But I can not understand the functionality of this education, what does? Ok access to videos of the smartphone, but you can not (for example, after the tap of a button) to enter its physically in the gallery of videos of the phone to be able to select one style PhotoChooserTasks?